# Extracting Specific Groups from a DataFrame under Specific Conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have a DataFrame as below where I want to extract groups that contain a row with (Name: J and Age: 33)

| X | Y | Name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | J | 33 |
| 1 | 3 | A | 47 |
| 1 | 4 | B | 53 |
| 1 | 4 | X | 22 |
| 2 | 3 | J | 33 |
| 2 | 3 | P | 80 |
| 2 | 4 | V | 90 |
| 2 | 4 | V | 93 |

Overall it would produce the table below, because the 1, 3 X/Y group contains J, 33 and the 2,3 X/Y group also contains a J, 33 row.

| X | Y | Name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | J | 33 |
| 1 | 3 | A | 47 |
| 2 | 3 | J | 33 |
| 2 | 3 | P | 80 |

I've been approaching this by iterating over the rows which has been far too slow and was wondering if there was a much faster way by using the groupby and apply/pipe methods in Pandas. Any help is appreciated

Example DF below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'X': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
    'Y': [3,3,4,4,3,3,4,4],
    'Name': ['J', 'A', 'B', 'X', 'V', 'P', 'J', 'V'],
    'Age': [33,47,53,22,33,80,33,93]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is with a groupby:

```py
# Get rows equal to ('J', 33)
check = df.loc(axis=1)[['Name','Age']].eq(('J', 33)).all(axis=1)
# run a groupby and get groups where True exists for any row in that group
check = check.groupby([df.X, df.Y]).transform('any')
#filter original dataframe
df.loc[check]

   X  Y Name  Age
0  1  3    J   33
1  1  3    A   47
4  2  3    J   33
5  2  3    P   80
```

Another option, still with a groupby:

```py
group = df.groupby(['X','Y'])
cond1 = group.Name.transform(lambda x: any(x == 'J'))
cond2 = group.Age.transform(lambda x: any(x == 33))
df.loc[cond1 & cond2]
   X  Y Name  Age
0  1  3    J   33
1  1  3    A   47
4  2  3    J   33
5  2  3    P   80
```

Comment: Can you explain why this so fast, is there any ideas in your mind that you would look into to making this faster. Also, just understanding why you chose to use functions that you did. Sorry for the questions but it just helps my understanding for the future.

Comment: No need to be sorry, we are all learners. It is relatively fast because they are vectorised operations. There could possibly be even faster options. The more you solve questions the more likely you'll see patterns to solving future questions

Comment: Not looking for an answer, but if you were to attempt to improve it do you have an idea how, or what direction you would go in?

Answer (score 0):

You can search for all unique `X` and `Y` values that contain `Name == J` and `Age == 33` and filter the dataframe afterwards:

```py
mask = (df['Name'] == 'J') & (df['Age'] == 33)

unique_x = df.loc[mask, 'X'].unique()
unique_y = df.loc[mask, 'Y'].unique()

print(df[df['X'].isin(unique_x) & df['Y'].isin(unique_y)])
```

Prints:

```
   X  Y Name  Age
0  1  3    J   33
1  1  3    A   47
4  2  3    J   33
5  2  3    P   80
```

---

EDIT: With updated question, a solution without `.groupby`:

```py
mask = (df['Name'] == 'J') & (df['Age'] == 33)

t = set(df.loc[mask, ['X', 'Y']].drop_duplicates().apply(tuple, 1))
out = df[df.loc[:, ['X', 'Y']].apply(lambda x: tuple(x) in t, axis=1)]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   X  Y Name  Age
0  1  3    J   33
1  1  3    A   47
4  2  3    J   33
5  2  3    P   80
```

Comment: This wont work if one of the desired values are on a row where Y is 4, at that point it just returns the entire DF as the unique values for X and Y are [1,2] and [3,4]